# how to make the last row in a UICollectionview to be sticky using swift 3

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview

I used multi directional scrolling with a custom flow layout in a  UICollectionView to create a numeric table.

The structure of the table should be like this. A numeric table which has the sum up value in the last row:

[image: The structure of the table should be like this. A numeric table which has the sum up value in the last row]

Now the first column and the first row of the table is static i.e sticky. I want the last row also to get Sticked at the bottom of the view. Kindly help me.

This is my current view of the table:

[image: This is my current view of the table]

Thank You in advance.

Comment: why won't you just create an `UIView` at the bottom?

Comment: I tried by adding Collection reusable view but it didn't work

Comment: @RJey Subclass a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. For the last item attribute which you want to be sticky add a property `zIndex = 1` and origin as a content offset of the `UICollectionView` :)

Comment: @RJey Welcome my friend! Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if section == sectionCount-1 {

    for item in 0...rowCount-1 {
         let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)                                
         if let attrs = cellAttrsDictionary[indexPath] {
              var frame = attrs.frame            
              if item == 0 {                 
                  // Assigning the size of the first column as 200
                  frame.size.width = 200
                  frame.origin.x = xOffset
              }

              // Configuration for the last row in the last cell.

              // Subtracting the Cell height from the entire Collection View height and assigning it as the frame for the last row of the Table i.e precisely on Y position.

              frame.origin.y = (collectionView?.frame.size.height)! + yOffset - CGFloat(CELL_HEIGHT)
              attrs.frame = frame
         }                 
    }
}
```